# Android button click event won't fire sometimes

Tags: android, button, android-activity

The onClick() event for my a button in my Android app won't fire.  The button is a "next" button in one activity in a series of configuration activities.  The first time I go through the series of configuration activities, the onClick() event fires fine.  However, if I back all the way out of my app (using the back button) and relaunch, the event never fires.  I've verified by putting a breakpoint in my next() method; the method that calls the subsequent activity.

Here's my code:

Button XML in my layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/gender_button_id"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="next"
    android:text="@string/gender_button" />
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_gender);
}

public void next(View view)
{
   Intent i = new Intent(this, WeightActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your log entries for when the button doe not work?

Comment: Where do I get this from?

Comment: lol! learning to read your log output is essential if you are going to develop Android apps. You run adb logcat from the command line or you look at the output in Eclipse in the logcat output tab underneath the code window

Comment: Sorry, I was confused because logcat wasnt' showing anything in it.  Turns out I had the wrong filter on.  There's a ton of stuff in there.  Any particular tag, or tags you think are relevant?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this jamesw.  I did a clean build and that seemed to fix the issue.  Guess something got hosed.

Comment: Yeah, a clean often fixes weird stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Put some **log/println** statement inside your next() ...what I can guess it will print your log/println onto console but will not start new Activity because **you might not have declared your activity in menifest** file